# Bluetooth printer not receiving sent data to print

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an android application in android studio and a part of it is sending a food order to the thermal printer via Bluetooth.

My app discovers all the Bluetooth devices in the area and when the printer is selected it's supposed to send a test print over. The printer's light changes to solid blue, indicating a Bluetooth connection however the data is never printed. I am using a [PL70e-BT printer](https://www.nelkoprint.com/products/nelko-bluetooth-thermal-shipping-label-printer-pl70e). Below is the listener inside my btScan() function which finds out the nearby Bluetooth devices.

I'm new to Kotlin so I don't fully understand how it's meant to work.

```kotlin
btlst.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, l ->
    val string = ADAhere.getItem(position) as HashMap<String, String>
    val prnName = string["A"]
    //binding.deviceName.setText(prnName)

    val device = pairedDevices.elementAt(position - 1) // Adjust the index to skip the empty item
    val prntrName = device.name
    val prnAddress = device.address

    // Define an array of UUIDs to try
    val uuidsToTry = arrayOf(
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),
        // Add more UUIDs if needed
    )

    // Try connecting with each UUID
    var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
    for (uuid in uuidsToTry) {
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
            socket.connect()

            // Check if pairing is required
            if (device.bondState != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                // Initiate pairing if not already bonded
                val pin = "0000" // Replace with your printer's PIN
                device.createBond()
                device.setPin(pin.toByteArray())
                showToast("Pin has been set")
            }

            showToast("Connection successful with UUID: $uuid")

            // Send test data and close the socket
            //val outputStream: OutputStream = socket.outputStream
            val outputStream = socket.outputStream
            val testData = "TEST"

            Log.d("Bluetooth status before", "Bluetooth Connection Status: ${socket?.isConnected}") //checks bluetooth status before message is sent
            Log.d("Message format", "Data Sent: $testData")                  //tests the format in which data was sent
            outputStream.write(testData.toByteArray())
            //outputStream.write(testData.toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))


            // Close the socket when done
            Thread.sleep(15000)
            socket.close()
            showToast("Data sent successfully!")
            Log.d("Bluetooth status after", "Bluetooth Connection Status: ${socket?.isConnected}") //checks bluetooth status after message is sent
            break // Exit the loop if successful
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Handle connection failure
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    if (socket == null) {
        showToast("Failed to connect with any UUID.")
    }

    dialog.dismiss()



}
```

I have tried two different ways of creating the OutputStream socket:

```
val outputStream: OutputStream = socket.outputStream
val outputStream = socket.outputStream
```

Two different ways of formatting the test print:

```
outputStream.write(testData.toByteArray())
outputStream.write(testData.toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))
```

Tried giving the printer more time to process the request with `Thread.sleep(15000)`

And also checked the bluetooth connection which is active before the data is sent and closes right after it's "done".